# Weaker condition for law of large numbers

Tags: probability

$X_k$'s are i.i.d. Suppose $X_k$ is symmetric and $E[|X_k|^{3/4}]<\infty$. Do we have $S_n/n \rightarrow 0$ either in probability or almost surely, where $S_n$ is the partial sum.

Comment: That's a curious moment condition. Where did you get that from?

Comment: basically a random one < 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**.

Take the standard Cauchy distribution:
$$\newcommand{\rd}{\,\mathrm{d}}
\mathbb E |X|^{3/4} = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3/4}}{\pi (1+x^2)} \rd x= \csc(\pi/8) < \infty \>,
$$
but $S_n/n$ is *equal in distribution* to $X$. That is, it is *also* standard Cauchy no matter how large $n$ becomes.

More generally, note that this same counterexample works for any $0 < p < 1$ since
$$
\frac{\pi}{2} \mathbb E|X|^p = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{x^p}{1+x^2} \rd x \leq 1 + \int_{1}^\infty x^{p-2} \rd x = \frac{2-p}{1-p} < \infty \> .
$$

Comment: Thank you. It's a nice example

Comment: Thanks. The Cauchy serves as a counterexample for *many* statements regarding probability and mathematical statistics. Usually, at least in a setting that admits continuous distributions, it's a good one to try out on any new conjecture or "result".